# File Android.png does not exist in Android Studio when create image asset

Tags: android-studio

When I try to create action icon in Image Asset of Android Studio I saw the error log: Android.png does not exist and I can not create action icon. Anyone can help me?

screenshot

[image]

Comment: It's stupid bug that I have been struggling for a few years. I wonder if anyone has reported this bug. Basically, it is just keeping dead link for resource.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This issue can be resolved by:**

Select *Launcher Icons*, definitely, there will be the previous linked file which was removed from the system. Just go there and choose some other file and the issue will be resolved automatically.

---

[image: .png file does not exist]

---

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an image wizard issue. Image asset wizard caches path to ic_launcher icon and can't find it. 
To resolve it you need repick ic_launcher image file for background layer and/or/maybe foreground layer.

Also you can use such command line tool like ack to find all strings 'burma_launcher.png' and manually edit finded files

Answer (score 0):

recommend that you use the material design style for action bar and tab icons, even if you support older Android versions. Use appcompat and other support libraries to deliver your material design UI to older platform versions.

As an alternative to Image Asset Studio, you can use Vector Asset Studio to create action bar and tab icons. Vector drawables are appropriate for simple icons and can reduce the size of your APK.

Comment: Thank you Sasikumar, can you explain more detail about using the material design style for action bar and tab icons? What tool or software should I use to create it?

Comment: I'll. Give you the link you can get more details about this
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/